# NSJSONSerialization - What is the proper value to specify no NSJSONWritingOptions for dataWithJSONObject:options:error:?

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsjsonserialization

Apple's documentation has the NSJSONWritingOptions enum with one constant defined: NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted, and says that "If this option is not set, the most compact possible JSON representation is generated."

I definitely want the most compact JSON representation.

My question is:  what is the proper value to pass the dataWithJSONObject:options:error: function if I don't want pretty printed, and why?

The NSJSONWritingOptions enum is defined as

```
enum {     NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted = (1UL << 0) }; typedef NSUInteger NSJSONWritingOptions;
```

I have read in a different post that 0 should be passed, but with no further explanation as to why it shouldn't be nil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be `nil` because it's an `NSUInteger`. So, you should pass `0`, which represents that the option is not set.

Comment: Why does 0 represent that the option is not set?  Could I also pass it 38374 (or some other random NSUInteger)?

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/writeJSONObject:toStream:options:error:): "Pass 0 to specify no options".

Comment: Thanks, I guess I missed that part, I jumped right to the options.

Comment: Or you can use `kNilOptions`.